# Mongoose - Search nested fields by joined text

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an object with an array of fields, some include select dropdowns, so the 'value' is just the id to a row in another table, I'd like to be able to search those by the text value, is this possible?

Here is are my collections:

records:

```
{
    ... <many properties>
    "description": "some text",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "key": "price",
            "value": "8999"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "key": "officer",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "key": "notes",
            "value": null
        }
    ]
}
```

fields collection / officer field definition:

```
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "options" : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "key" : "officer",
    "label" : "Officer",
    "type" : "select"
}
```

fieldoptions collection:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "key" : "none",
    "label" : "None",
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "key" : "picard",
    "label" : "Picard",
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "key" : "riker",
    "label" : "Riker",
}
```

I want to search search all records for the word 'picard' for example, and have the system find any matches in ANY property on it, including the 'fields', but most fields just have an id in their 'value' property to other collections, like officers above.

In sql terms, this would be like joining on id and searching the joined table text value:

foo:

```
id
description
bar_id
```

bar:

```
id
description
```

query:

```
SELECT foo.*, bar.*
FROM foo
JOIN bar ON foo.bar_id = bar.id
WHERE foo.description like xxx OR bar.description like xxx
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What field you need to refer in another collection. Are you looking for lookup in mongo?

Comment: I updated the question description at the end to make it more clear, basically I want to search all records for a text work, and pull matches, but I don't know how to search the fields array when values are not text, but ids to other collections.

Comment: I also added an sql example to make things more clear.